# JAVASCRIPT/BOOTSTRAP- How to auto-select option on another select based on the option of first select?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to auto-select the option `value="blank"` from `id="month"` based on the selection of `data-val='OPEN'` from `id="week"`(1st select). Also I want the select `id="month"` to be disabled if `data-val='OPEN'` is selected. How do I trigger this one? I've already used `data-val` to trigger the select `id="Delivery"`.

```js
var category = document.getElementById('Delivery');
document.getElementById('week').onchange = function() {
  var optionSelected = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  if (optionSelected.textContent != '-') {
    if (optionSelected.dataset.val === 'OPEN') {
      category.value = 'OPEN';
    } else {
      category.value = 'CLOSE';
    }
  } else {
    category.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <div>
    <label for="week">Dispatch schedule:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="week" id="week" title="Delivery" style="width:110px;">
            
            <option data-val='OPEN' value="READY">Ready</option>
             
            <option data-val='CLOSE' value="1st WEEK">1st Week</option>
             
            <option data-val='CLOSE' value="2nd WEEK">2nd Week</option>
              
            <option data-val='CLOSE' value="3rd WEEK">3rd Week</option>
            </select>
  </div>


  <div class="myselection">
    <select name="Delivery" id="Delivery" disabled="">
            <option value="OPEN">Open</option>
            <option value="CLOSE">Close</option>
            </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="month">Select Month: </label>
    <select class="form-control" name="month" id="month" style="width:70px;" >
                                             
            <option value="blank">- - -</option>
            <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
            <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
            <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
            <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
            <option value="May">May</option>
            <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
            <option value="Jul">Jul</option>
            <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
            <option value="Sep">Sep</option>
            <option value="Oct">Oct</option>
            <option value="Nov">Nov</option>
            <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
             </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you use same method as you used for `category`.?

Comment: yes, but how do I add another data-val in the first option?  Also I want the select id="month" to be disabled if data-val='OPEN'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use same method as you used for `category` option.

```js
var category = document.getElementById('Delivery');
var _month = document.getElementById('month');
document.getElementById('week').onchange = function() {
  var optionSelected = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  if (optionSelected.textContent != '-') {
    if (optionSelected.dataset.val === 'OPEN') {
      category.value = 'OPEN';
      _month.value = 'blank';
      _month.disabled = true;
    } else {
      category.value = 'CLOSE';
      _month.disabled = false;
    }
  } else {
    category.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="control-group">
  <div>
    <label for="week">Dispatch schedule:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="week" id="week" title="Delivery" style="width:110px;">
      <option data-val='OPEN' value="READY">Ready</option>
      <option data-val='CLOSE' value="1st WEEK">1st Week</option>
      <option data-val='CLOSE' value="2nd WEEK">2nd Week</option>
      <option data-val='CLOSE' value="3rd WEEK">3rd Week</option>
    </select>
  </div>


  <div class="myselection">
    <select name="Delivery" id="Delivery" disabled="">
      <option value="OPEN">Open</option>
      <option value="CLOSE">Close</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="month">Select Month: </label>
    <select class="form-control" name="month" id="month" style="width:70px;" disabled="">
      <option value="blank">- - -</option>
      <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
      <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
      <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
      <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
      <option value="May">May</option>
      <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
      <option value="Jul">Jul</option>
      <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
      <option value="Sep">Sep</option>
      <option value="Oct">Oct</option>
      <option value="Nov">Nov</option>
      <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to add additional data-val's with bootstrap. But if you are open to adding a few extra lines of javascript it can be achieved.

```js
var category = document.getElementById('Delivery');
var month = document.getElementById('month');

document.getElementById('week').onchange = function() {
  var optionSelected = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  if (optionSelected.textContent != '-') {
    if (optionSelected.dataset.val === 'OPEN') {
      category.value = 'OPEN';
      month.disabled = true;
      month.value = 'blank';
    } else {
      category.value = 'CLOSE';
      month.disabled = false;      
    }
  } else {
    category.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="control-group">
        <div>
        <label for="week">Dispatch schedule:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="week" id="week" title="Delivery" style="width:110px;">

        <option data-val='OPEN' value="READY">Ready</option>

        <option data-val='CLOSE' value="1st WEEK">1st Week</option>

        <option data-val='CLOSE' value="2nd WEEK">2nd Week</option>

        <option data-val='CLOSE' value="3rd WEEK">3rd Week</option>
        </select>
        </div>


        <div class="myselection">
        <select name="Delivery" id="Delivery" disabled="">
        <option value="OPEN">Open</option>
        <option value="CLOSE">Close</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <div>
        <label for="month">Select Month: </label>
        <select class="form-control" name="month" id ="month" style="width:70px;" disabled=true>

        <option value="blank">- - -</option>
        <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
        <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
        <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
        <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
        <option value="May">May</option>
        <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
        <option value="Jul">Jul</option>
        <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
        <option value="Sep">Sep</option>
        <option value="Oct">Oct</option>
        <option value="Nov">Nov</option>
        <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
         </select> 
        </div>
</div>
```